# Are there any badges or awards for maximum consecutive days visit on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I visited more than 12 consecutive days on Stack Overflow, but I have not received any badges or awards.

Comment: I think I got a gold star for visiting 100 days in a row, so keep going.  But this question is off-topic, expect it to be closed very soon.  You might find more detail on badges and how to earn them in the Help Centre.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397

Comment: I *assume* you're after the [fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badge.

Comment: What made you expect one after more than 12 consecutive days? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Enthusiast</kbd>

[Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast) badge can be earned by visiting the site each day for 30 consecutive days. (Days are counted in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).).

---

<kbd>Fanatic</kbd>

[Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badge can be earned by visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).).